# How to define a delegate using Delegate.CreateDelegate instead of Func<>?

Tags: c#, delegates, func

I have a method and two delegate like below. It is running in this way. But I want to use Delegate.CreateInstance. The types of the dx and the dy must be `Func<IEnumerable<Foo>>`. Like below the fx and fy. They must not be `Func<int, IEnumerable<Foo>>`.

```
public class Test {
    private IEnumerable<T> CreateItems<T>(int count) where T : class
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < count; i++)
        {
            yield return (T)Activator.CreateInstance(typeof(T), i.ToString());
        }
    }

    public List<T> TestMethod<T>(int i = 1) where T : class
    {
        return CreateItems<T>(i).ToList();
    }

    public void TestRun()
    {
        const int Count = 5;
        Func<IEnumerable<Foo>> fx = () => this.TestMethod<Foo>(Count);
        Func<IEnumerable<Foo>> fy = () => this.TestMethod<Foo>();
        var lfx = fx.Invoke();
        var lfy = fy.Invoke();
        var dx = Delegate.CreateDelegate( ?? );
        var dy = Delegate.CreateDelegate( ?? );
        var ldx = dx.DynamicInvoke();
        var ldy = dy.DynamicInvoke();
    }
}
```

Comment: `Func<IEnumerable<int, Foo>>` that type doesn't even exist.

Comment: I am sorry, I wrote wrong. It is Func<int, IEnumerable<Foo>>

Comment: What *actual type* of delegate are you trying to create though? It's really unclear what you're trying to achieve.

Comment: Why do you expect that an instance method with one parameter can be used as a delegate with no parameters directly? (Parameters with default values are still parameters that need to be passed in.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want the type to be `Func<IEnumerable<Foo>>`, then you cannot create that **directly** via `Delegate.CreateDelegate` since they require two parameters: the instance (aka `this`), and the integer `i`. Even the form shown in `fx` *has* an `i` - it just happens to be supplied by the compiler. If `TestMethod` didn't take parameters, it could be done via:

```
var dy = (Func<IEnumerable<Foo>>) Delegate.CreateDelegate(
    typeof(Func<IEnumerable<Foo>>),
    this,
    GetType().GetMethod("TestMethod").MakeGenericMethod(typeof(Foo))
);
```

To do this (partial application) dynamically, you would need to create a type that has the instance (`this`), the value to inject (the `i`), and a method that *calls* `TestMethod<Foo>` with those values. Which is **exactly** what the compiler does for you here:

```
Func<IEnumerable<Foo>> fx = () => this.TestMethod<Foo>(Count);
```

That basically creates:

```
internal class <>_squiggle {
    public Test @this;
    public IEnumerable<Foo> Method() {
        return @this.TestMethod<Foo>(5);
    }
}
```

and:

```
var capture = new <>_squiggle { @this = this };
var fx = new Func<IEnumerable<Foo>>(capture.Method);
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. But the method in the func must take a parameter from outside. I think @CodesInChaos is right. Probably, It is imposible.

Comment: @sinanakyazici indeed, I said "you cannot create that directly via `Delegate.CreateDelegate`". The rest was context on *why* you can't, and how you can work around it. If you **really care enough**, it could be done at runtime using `ILGenerator`, but it would be stupidly convoluted.

Comment: ILGenerator is very complex. I want to do in this way to I want its to be simple. So I can't use it. This concerns a part of my project. So I need to find a new thing for this part.

Comment: @sinanakyazici "I want its to be simple". What you ask **is not** simple; the compiler makes it *look* simple, but actually the capture-context code used in lambdas and anonymous-methods is some of the most complex code in the compiler. What you are trying to do has inherent complexity.

Answer (score 2):

That's impossible. There is no way you can fit an *instance method* with signature `A F(X x)` into a `Func<A>` directly.

It's possible to bind the first parameter of a method into the delegate directly, but no additional parameters. In your case the instance `this` is that first parameter, and you can't bind a value for `i`.

I guess your misunderstanding is how parameters with default values work. They're still parameters that need to be filled in by the caller. It's just that the C# compiler does that for you.

You will need a wrapper of some kind with the correct signature. That can be a lambda, or some other helper method. In your case I'd overload the method `TestMethod` instead of using a default parameter.